# How to search Work Order records from Netsuite using api?

Tags: c#, netsuite

I have to fetch Work Order record from NetSuite based on work order number, I can do that using a saved search but would like to do it without it, so as i do not have a to create another saved search record in production. My code is not returning any result, however the search is successful.

here is the code i am using:

```
        TransactionSearch ts = new TransactionSearch();
        TransactionSearchBasic tsb = new TransactionSearchBasic();

        // work order number
        SearchStringField sfTranId = new SearchStringField();
        sfTranId.@operator = SearchStringFieldOperator.@is;
        sfTranId.searchValue = workorder;
        sfTranId.operatorSpecified = true;

        // type
        SearchEnumMultiSelectField sfType = new SearchEnumMultiSelectField();
        sfType.@operator = SearchEnumMultiSelectFieldOperator.anyOf;
        sfType.operatorSpecified = true;
        sfType.searchValue = new String[] {"_workOrder"};

        tsb.tranId = sfTranId;
        tsb.type = sfType;

        ts.basic = tsb;
        tsa3.criteria = ts;

        // perform the search
        SearchResult res = _service.search(ts);
        res.pageSizeSpecified = true;

        if (res.status.isSuccess)
        {
            SearchRow[] searchRows = res.searchRowList;
            if (searchRows != null && searchRows.Length >= 1)
            {
                TransactionSearchRow tranRow = (TransactionSearchRow)searchRows[0];
                if (tranRow.basic.internalId != null && tranRow.basic.internalId.Length > 0)
                {
                    woResult = tranRow.basic.internalId[0].searchValue.internalId;
                }                    
            }                
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized my mistake, basic search returns RecordList and not SearchRowList.